# Biggest common sub-string search asymptotics

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

What is the function of Big-O in case where we use brute-force on two strings to find the biggest common sub-string. Please can you explain the underlying logic to the resulting formula corresponding to that Big-O.

How it is changing when we are looking for a common biggest sub-string in three different strings at same time. Also with brute-force.

Comment: How brute is your brute force? The brutest I can imagine is to loop through all of the $\frac{n^2-n}{2}\frac{m^2-m}{2}$ _pairs_ of substrings from each of the two strings and for each pair check if the substrings are equal (which takes another factor of $O(\min(n,m))$ time), for a total complexity of $O(n^2m^2\min(n,m))$. Less brute approaches can be imagined, though.

Comment: I meant when we start by comparing all consecutive 2 symbols from the first string to the first in the second, till we do these for all occurrences of 2 symbols in both of them, then we choose 3 symbols and repeat the operation, then more, until we get a number of symbols for which there are no common occurrence.